# jQuery $(this) syntax question

Tags: jquery, this

Is this a valid selector?  If not, what's the correct way?

```
$($(this)+' childElement')....
```

Comment: Think about what `$(this)` returns... no string, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to directly select a children of 'this' or do you want to dynamically select a children by appending the id of 'this' with children's id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 $(this).find("childrenSelector")
```

Comment: I like @Justin's answer better than this because I thought I remembered reading that his method has better performance. I could be wrong though.

Comment: According to this test, using context is *slightly* faster than find, although both give similar performance: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-with-find

Comment: Thanks Justin. Gave +1 to yours.

Answer (score 7):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
$('childElement', $(this))
```

Basically it will search for `childElement` within the context of the current element, `this`.

---

For more information, see the documentation for the [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function. In particular, the following excerpt explains the second argument and how it is equivalent to using `find`:

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, if within a callback function we wish to do a search for an element, we can restrict that search:
>
> ```
> $('div.foo').click(function() {
>   $('span', this).addClass('bar');
> });
> ```
>
> Since we've restricted the span selector to the context of this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`.

Comment: Can you show me where this is found in the jQuery docs?  I've never seen anything like that before?  I would like to read how it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this).find('childrenSelector');
```

Comment: @Ben - And why wasn't this the accepted answer? Same as what you accepted, but answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

$(this).children('.element');

Comment: i've been tripped up using this one since it only goes one level deep.