# jquery selector on textarea and textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a  div with ID as **MQ** , i have to get the values of **textbox and textareas** within this **div id MQ using JQuery foreach** . i have tried following , but no results.

```
$('div#MQ :text,textarea').each(function(){

$('div#MQ input[type="text"],textarea).each
```

kindly let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#MQ').find('textarea,:text').each( function(){
  var result = $(this).val(); // do something with each element's value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, basically it will find `text` and `textarea` attributes within the `#MQ` div:

```
$('text,textarea', "#MQ").each(function(){
```

For an explanation of this syntax, please see [jquery-this-syntax-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922285/jquery-this-syntax-question/4922322#4922322).